# How to read a text file to a list in c#?

Tags: c#, text

A line in the text file would look like this:

```
1056 Mark Supers Swagminator test32@gmail.com 3500
```

They all have to go into their own property for a new object, and then the next lines will go into their own objects. How can this be done?

This is supposed to work as a list with 'accounts' and this is the account informations, with name and so on.

Comment: you'll have to figure out the delimiter between the data you want. Is it a tab ("\t")?

Comment: Can't the delimiter be the space between them? else im not sure i understand the question.

Comment: This is trivial. What have you tried so far? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: and im not sure what you mean Grant Winney, sry

Comment: Im not asking anyone to write the code for me, but maybe point me in the direction of where i can find out how to do  it

Comment: `Mark Supers Swagminator` is a single name but it contains spaces, so space cannot be the delimiter. Otherwise you need to quote every field like in `"Mark Supers Swagminator"`. But then you should also use an available CSV parser like the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` class which supports quoting characters. You could also use the tab-character as delimiter, then you could use `String.Split('\t')`.

Comment: var propertyArray = entry.Split(' '); ? If you are producing your entries on your own, you could take a better delimiter than a space

Comment: And like Tim Schmelter mentioned, you should use a different delimiter for entries, because you might get in trouble with names. "Mark Supers Swagminator" will be detected as three different properties, if you keep using a space delimiter. Better use a % between entries, so that it would look like `1056%Mark Supers Swagminator%test32@gmail.com%3500`, but thats just my opinion

Comment: Mark Supers and Swagminator is a single name, but still needs to be put into 3 different properties

Comment: Just play around with delimiters then

Comment: but yeah i get the point, it is a good idea to use a different delimiter

Comment: Do you mind, if I post it as an answer and you accept it? Im fairly low on reputation (51) and am interested in some more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have googled that very easy i think. but here is a ok and easy way to do it. the commends should explain what i am doing.

```
    // Create Class that holds the Attributes for you
    // I am using auto properties here
    // if you don't know what a property is pls google it - you need to know that
    class AccountData
    {
        public int firstNumber { get; set; }

        public string firstString { get; set; }

        public string secondString { get; set; }

        public string thirdString { get; set; }

        public string mailAddress { get; set; }

        public int lastNumber { get; set; }

    }

    List<AccountData> Parser(string FileLocationWithName)
    {

        // FileLocationWithName is something like "C:\MyFolder\MyFile.txt"
        // If you want to write a backsplash (\) you need to write \\
        // or you can use a @ bevore the string
        // without @: "C:\\MyFolder\\MyFile.txt"
        // with @: @"C:\MyFolder\MyFile.txt"

        // Create your list
        List<AccountData> resultList = new List<AccountData>();

        // Oben a new FileStream - a StreamReader is good
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileLocationWithName))
        {

            // Read the Whole file <=> sr is not at the end of the stream
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                // read a line and split it into the strings
                string line = sr.ReadLine();

                var elementsOfLine = line.Split(' ');

                // create a new object of your accountData class and fill it with the string elements
                var tempElement = new AccountData();
                tempElement.firstNumber = int.Parse(elementsOfLine[0]);
                tempElement.firstString = elementsOfLine[1];
                tempElement.secondString = elementsOfLine[2];
                tempElement.thirdString = elementsOfLine[3];
                tempElement.mailAddress = elementsOfLine[4];
                tempElement.lastNumber = int.Parse(elementsOfLine[5]);

                resultList.Add(tempElement);
            }
        }

        // return your list
        return resultList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

from: [Reading a text file word by word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740557/reading-a-text-file-word-by-word)

```
using (var mappedFile1 = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(filePath))
    {
        using (Stream mmStream = mappedFile1.CreateViewStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(mmStream, ASCIIEncoding.ASCII))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();
                    string lineWords = line.Split(' ');
                    number = lineWords[0];
                    name = lineWords[1]; //and so on..
                }
            }  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why the heck would you use a memory mapped file?

Answer (score 0):

```
string line = "1056%Mark%Supers%Swagminator%test32@gmail.com%3500";
var propertyArray = line.Split('%');
foreach (string entry in propertyArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry);
}
```

This prints every entry. You can use each entry as a simple object within your array.
`propertyArray[0]` would be `1056`

Just be careful about the size. If someone had 4 names your email address would move from `propertyArray[4]` to `propertyArray[5]`